# finding where is a function complex differentiable and holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, computational-complexity

$$f(z)=\sin|z|^2$$
Where is this function complex differentiable and holomorphic?
Generally I have to use the Cauchy-Riemann teorem:
$$
\begin{split}
u_{x} &=v_{y}\\
u_{y}&=-v_{x}
\end{split}
$$
*Solution*

1. First attempt:
   $$
   f(z)=\sin|z|^2=f(z)=\sin|x+iy|^2=\sin(x^2+2ixy-y^2)\ldots
   $$ This is not going anywhere...
2. Second attempt:
   $$f(z)=\sin|z|^2=\sin z\overline{z}=\sin(x^2+y^2),
   $$ which shouldn't be complex differential anywhere because it has no complex part => it's not holomorphic?
3. The real solution:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   f(z) &=\sin|z|^2=\sin z\overline{z}\\
   \frac{df}{d\overline{z}} &=z\cos z\overline{z}=0\\
   z=0 &\implies\cos z\overline{z}=0\implies \cos z\overline{z}=0\implies|z|=\sqrt{\pm\pi/2+2K\pi}\ldots
   \end{align}
   $$
   My question is can I solve this problem using some of my attemps(I need to use Cauchy-Riemann)?

In the real solution, why did we had to differentiate the function and make it equal to 0, where does this come from?

Is there a clear algorithmic way to decide if a function is holomorphic or I just have to use my imagination ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. Note that, from
$$
f(z)=\sin|z|^2=\sin(x^2+y^2)
$$
we have 
$$
f(z)=u+iv=\sin(x^2+y^2)+i\cdot 0
$$
so:
$$
u_x=2x\cos|z|^2 \qquad u_y=2y\cos|z|^2 \qquad v_x=v_y=0 
$$

so $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ iff $ z=0 $ or $ \cos |z|^2=0$ that is 
$|z|^2=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$.

The other solution is an application of the  [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives)  that says that a complex function $f(z)$ is [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Definition) iff 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0
$$

Comment: if we use Wirtinger derivative and see that a function is holomorphic, would that mean that the function is complex differentiable?

Comment: yes,''holomorphic'' and ''complex differentiable'' are synonymous.

Comment: @EmilioNovati No, they are not synonymous. A function can be complex differentiable in a point without being holomorphic there (which would require that the function is complex differentiable in a whole neighborhood of that point).